# Does Collections.unmodifiableList(list) require a lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, collections

I have a `productList` maintained in a file named `Products.java`

```
private List<String> productList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

Now creating a synchronized list, will ensure that operations like add/remove will have a implicit lock and I don't need to lock these operations explicitily.

I have a function exposed which returns an `unmodifiableList` of this list.

```
public List getProductList(){

 return Collections.unmodifiableList(productList);
}
```

In my application, various threads can call this function at the same time. So do I need to put a `synchronized` block when converting a List into an unmodifiable List or will this be already taken care of since I am using a sychronizedList ?

TIA.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281056/how-to-synchronize-unmodifiable-collections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't need to be synchronized since the unmodifiable list is wrapping the synchronized one. But there's not much use for synchronizing on an unmodifiable list, other than for the purpose of iteration, which [requires](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) manual synchronization regardless:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
>     ...
> synchronized (list) {
>     Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>         foo(i.next());
> }
> ```
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

EDIT: As Ferrybig points out, it's actually not possible to synchronize safely with the unmodifiable wrapper. You may want to consider an alternative thread-safety solution, such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: "But there's not much use for synchronizing on an unmodifiable list" this statement is at best misleading and at worst wrong. It is not just code that writes to shared data that must take care of locking. Code that reads shared data must use a lock or a mechanismthat ensures safe publication.

Answer (score 4):

The only place where the synchronized should be used is when you loop over it, as explained by the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:

However, you cannot do that once you wrapped it in a `unmodifiableList`, making it unsafe for a return result. It may return corrupted data in the case of concurrent access.

Instead of returning your backend list, it may be better to return a copy of the backend, so the calling doesn't need to worry about synchronized performance.

```
public List getProductList(){
    synchronized (productList) {
       return new ArrayList<>(productList);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I go by the approach of returning a new ArrayList, then during the time I am accessing the returned list, some elements might be added or deleted in the original list which I don't want to miss out. I always need the original list in my case.

Comment: In that case, you may want to make the backend list a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` like @shmosel said, those lists don't need to be wrapped in a `synchronizedList` block, and don't suffer `ConcurrentModificationException` when looping. I recommend you wait at least an hour before accepting any answer, I see that this question is becoming popular.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to put the synchronized block.

Comment: As you can see in shmosel's and Ferrybig's answers, this is incorrect. It's also quite useless as an answer since you provide no information to back up your statement.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to get a snapshot everytime,

```
list = get snapshot
{
    work on the list
}
discard list // GC it
```

since the snapshot is a constant, frozen data structure, client can access it freely.

But if the client accesses a data structure that may be modified by another party, it gets problematic. Forget about concurrency issues; think about the semantics of the following code

```
{
    n = list.size();
    list.get(n-1);
}
```

`get(n-1)` may fail, because the list may have shrunk when it's called.

To have some kind of consistency guarantee, the client side must provide explicit transaction demarcations during the session of access, like

```
acquire lock // preferably a read-lock
{
    work on the list
}
release lock
```

Note that this code is not simpler than the snapshot solution. And the client can still "miss out" updates, just like the snapshot solution.

And you have to decide whether you want to force client codes to perform this kind of locking.

It's not without merits of course; it can be better in performance than the snapshot solution if the list is big and updates are infrequent.

If this approach is more appropriate for the application, we may design something like

```
interface CloseableList extends List, Closeable {}

public CloseableList readProducts() // acquire read-lock when called

-- client code
try{CloseableList list = readProducts())
{
    ....
}   
// on close(), release the read-lock
```

If client only needs to iterate the products, we can use java8 Stream

```
final ReadWriteLock lock = ...

private ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
// modifications to `productList` must be protected by write lock

// javadoc: reader must close the stream!
public Stream readProducts()
{
    lock.readLock().lock();
    return productList.stream().onClose( lock.readLock()::unlock );
}

-- client code
try(Stream products = readProducts())
{
    ...
}
```

We may also design the API to take in the client code so that we can surround it with protections

```
public void readProducts(Consumer<List> action)
{
    lock read

    action.accept(productList);

    finally unlock read
}

-- client code
readProducts(list->
{
    ...
});
```